# Postgresql - Create role to connect to database and revoke all other permissions

Tags: postgresql, role, multi-tenant, database-user

I have an application which is configured with the multitenancy strategy of "single database multi schema".

Now I want to create a role which can have only specific permission that is to :

1. connect to the database
2. should be able to switch role.

Please help/guide me to create the as per the above requirement.

No other object (like other schema, tables those schema) in the database should be visible for this role.

So that I can use this role to login and based on the tenant I can switch to another role which can have access to a particular schema only .

Answer (score 0):

You should create that role with `NOINHERIT` and make it a member of all the other roles. Then the role does not inherit any privileges (so it has no permissions other than those that were granted to `PUBLIC`), but it can use `SET ROLE` to become any of the roles it is a member of.

Note that you can always run `RESET ROLE` to revert to the original role, then `SET ROLE` to become any of the other roles, so it is not safe to let a user issue arbitrary SQL statements after `SET ROLE`.